# Proof of conditions for polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Find the conditions for the roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ of the equation $x^3-ax^2+bx-c=0$ to be in: $(i)$A.P.; $(ii)$G.P.
If the roots  are not in A.P. and if $\alpha+\lambda,\ \beta+\lambda,\ \gamma+\lambda$ are in G.P., prove that $\lambda$ is given by a cubic equation.

I've got the solution for $(i)\ 2a^3-9ab+27c=0$ and $(ii)\ a^3c=b^3$

But how to prove the cubic equation for $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x)=x^3-ax^2+bx-c$, then the polynomial with roots $\alpha+\lambda, \beta+\lambda, \gamma+\lambda$ is:
$$p(x-\lambda)  =(x-\lambda)^3-a(x-\lambda)^2+b(x-\lambda)-c$$
$$=x^3-(3\lambda+a)x^2+(3\lambda^2+2a\lambda+b)x-(\lambda^3+a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c)$$

You already know from $(ii)$, the condition on coefficients for these roots to be in GP, so use that and simplify to get the cubic for $\lambda$. i.e.
$$(3\lambda+a)^3(\lambda^3+a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c)=(3\lambda^2+2a\lambda+b)^3$$
$$\iff (2a^3+27c-9ab)\lambda^3+(a^4+27ac-3a^2b-9b^2)\lambda^2+(a^3b+9a^2c-6ab^2)\lambda+(a^3c-b^3)=0$$

This remains a cubic as long as $2a^3+27c\neq 9ab$, which as per the condition in $(i)$, is ensured if the original roots are not in A.P.

Comment: Oh, thanks @macavity. I've got it right before. I just lost in the tedious expansion. Thanks so much for proof.